# Azure SQL Database Elastic Pool Resource Limit Exceeded - How to Resolve?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure

I'm encountering an issue with my Azure SQL Database where I'm receiving the following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Resource ID : 1. The request limit for the elastic pool is 400 and has been reached.

Details:
Azure SQL Databases with an elastic pool using 250 DTU.

This issue is occurring for all Azure SQL Databases in that specific pool. The pool has a DTU of 250. This issue is occurring for around 10 hours, besides that I am not able to query any database in the pool.

Is there a way around this? Would it be possible to kill all requests made to databases in that pool? I have been trying to upgrade the pool to 500 DTU but that is a long running operation, meanwhile all production databases are unavailable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are experiencing this issue, it means that the limit of concurrent workers has been reached. As a temporary workaround you can try to set max degree of parallelism to 1 on each database.

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET MAXDOP = 1;
```

Queries will probably run slowly in consequence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We couldn't query any database at that time. The issue has been resolved for now by creating a ticket through Azure. We will receive an RCA report shortly and will post an update.